# Iterating through dictionary list to search through directory to find files and copy them to new location

Tags: python, arcpy

I am relatively new to Python and having trouble figuring out what i am missing in my code.  What i am attempting to do is to create a dictionary containing a list of values and then use that dictionary to search a directory for file names then copy those files to a new folder (named after the key, which is already created). The key is a contract name and the values are contract plan sheets so each contract has anywhere 2 to 100 sheets. I got the code to work when each key only had one value, but now that it is a list it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am using `arcpy.da.searchcursor` to append the values to a dictionary.
Then i am using `itervalues` to iterate through the dictionary values i get the error
`ValueError: too many values to unpack.`

```
recDCT = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (deviceFC, [contract, RECDOC]) as curs:
    for row in curs:
        if row[1] <> None and row[0] <> None:
            if row[0] in recDCT.keys():
                recDCT[row[0]].append(row[1])
            else:
                recDCT[row[0]] = [row[1]]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for key, value in recDCT.itervalues():
        if value in files:
            shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + value), os.path.abspath(outLoc + '/' + key))
```

I expect the script to copy the all of the files for that key into the specified folderfile to the new folder.

**Update, figured out the solution I needed to use a `for` loop to call each key before iterating through the list.

```
recDCT = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (deviceFC, [contract, CurrDP]) as curs:
    for row in curs:
        if row[1] is not None and row[0] is not None:
            if row[0] in recDCT.keys():
                recDCT[row[0]].append(row[1])
            else:
                recDCT[row[0]] = [row[1]]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for key in recDCT:
        for value in recDCT[key]:
            if value in files:
                shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + value), os.path.abspath(outLoc + '/'+ key))
                a += 1
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: `<>` isn't an operator in python

Comment: Use `is not` instead of `<>`

Answer (score 0):

Hey first of all as said before `<>` is not an python operator. In python for many objects Truth Value Testing is available. This means that empty objects or non initialized objects return false in a boolean context an otherwise true.

For example:

```
bool([]) -> False
bool([1]) -> True
bool(None) -> False
```

For you example you can simply go replace `if row[1] <> None and row[0] <> None:` with the following code. This is more readable and more pythonic:

```
if row[1] and row[0]:
```